# Puppet - change permission of file with variable

Tags: regex, puppet

How would you use puppet to change the permissions of a file which does not have a consistent name?

My task is to manage a binary that has the date appended to the end of it like so:

```
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       18 Oct 25 18:46 apbridge -> ./apbridge20131025
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root       18 Oct 25 18:46 apbridge1025 -> ./apbridge20131025
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root     2914 Oct 25 18:46 apbridge20131025
```

apbridge20131025 has the wrong permissions. Normally the following would change it:

```
  file  {'/root/alpsSim/alps_simulator_r7537/tester/apbridge20131025':
    owner   =>  'root',
    group   =>  'root',
    ensure  =>  file,
    mode    => '0755',
  }
```

However because I can not predict what numbers apbridge will end in, this will be very likely to break.

I don't have control over the name of apbridgexxxxx as it is installed by a 3rd party script. The numbers at the end represent the day it was installed.

Is there a way to use a wildcard in a puppet file resource declaration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you make use of exec:

```
exec { 'apbridge':
  command => 'find /root/alpsSim/alps_simulator_r7537/tester/ -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "apbridge*" -exec chmod 755 {} \;',
  path    => '/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin',
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Normally I would recommend against using `exec` in Puppet in general, but in this case, `chmod` is idempotent - you will get the same results however you run it. There's also the slight benefit of Puppet not having to calculate a md5 hash for each file that it tries to change the permission for.

That said, a more elegant way to ensure permissions would be to set them on the directory containing the files recursively - assuming only the `apbridge*` files are present.

```
file  {'/root/alpsSim/alps_simulator_r7537/tester':
    owner   =>  'root',
    group   =>  'root',
    ensure  =>  directory,
    recurse => true,
    mode    => '0755',
}
```